# Jest automock is not mocking axios when importing a function that use axios

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I've been struggling to find a solution to this so that's why I've decided to open this topic. I want to test the following code using jest:

```
const axios = require('axios')

const findUserById = async (user_id) => {

  let { data: { data: user } } = await axios({
    method: 'get',
    baseURL: process.env.url,
    url: '/find-user',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': process.env.token,
      'id': user_id,
    },
  })

  if (!Object.keys(user).length) {
    user = null
  }
    
  return user
}

module.exports = {
  findUserById,
}
```

And reading the jest documentation I found that to mock jest modules I should first import **axios** and auto mocking the module using **jest.mock**. Comparing both (mine and the example) I can't really catch the difference.

```
const axios = require('axios')

const { findUserById } = require('../../../src/functions//find-user-by-id')

jest.mock('axios')

describe('findUserById', () => {

  it('should return null', async () => {

    axios.mockResolvedValue({
      data: {
        data: {},
      },
    })

    const user_id = 'non-valid-user-id'

    const user = await findUserById(user_id)

    expect(axios).toHaveBeenCalledWith()
    expect(user).toBe(null)

  })

})
```

When running the test, it throw me an error **Invalid value "undefined" for header "Authorization"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to mock the default export of `axios`.

```
const axios = jest.fn()


jest.mock('./axios', () => {
  return {
    default: axios,
  };
});
```

Comment: It didn't work. Actually it showed this error: axios.mockResolvedValue is not a function. Do you think common js instead of ES6 might influence on this? I have no clue in how figure this out. :(

Comment: I tested a similar code when I got home with ES6 and the test worked as expected, so jest.mock doesn't work when we are importing a function using require statements apparently. Is there any other way that I can achieve the same result as ES6 but using common js?

Comment: How is your the current Test looking? Did you do something like `jest.fn(). mockResolvedValue(...)`? Furthermore [i found a hint](https://medium.com/codeclan/mocking-es-and-commonjs-modules-with-jest-mock-37bbb552da43) within the docs of jest. And [this article](https://medium.com/codeclan/mocking-es-and-commonjs-modules-with-jest-mock-37bbb552da43). Maybe it can help you to find the solution.